# javascript, merge two arrays by index

Tags: javascript

Here are two arrays:

`const a = [1, null, 2, null]`

`const b = [null, null, 3, 4, null]`

**Note: The length of `a` and `b` is not fixed.**

I want elements of `b` replace elements of `a` by index if the element is not null.

expect value:

`[1, null, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  const result = b.map((el, i) => el === null ? a[i] : el);
  result.push(...a.slice(b.length));
```

Just map to a new array.

Comment: And if the only falsey values of `b` are `null`, you can use `||` (might, or might not be the case)

Comment: thanks. The length of `a` and `b` is not fixed. Does it work fine?

Comment: @novaline right, edited, [now it does](http://jsbin.com/hoqutiwoqo/edit?console)

Answer (score 0):

You can use map() function

```
var x=b.length+1;
b.concat(a);
var c=b.map(function(el, index) {
if(a[index]!=null && b[index]==null){
return b[index]=a[index];
else{
return b[index]
}
console.log(c.slice(0,x));
```

Comment: if the length of `a` bigger than `b`, it does not work